# Can Oracle GoldenGate work between different version of Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-replication

Can we use Oracle GoldenGate to sync data between different versions of Oracle ?

Our source database is 11.2.0.4 and target is 19.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Oracle GoldenGate can work between different versions of Oracle databases.

GoldenGate supports replicating data between different versions of Oracle databases, such as replicating data from an Oracle 11g database to an Oracle 12c database, or vice versa. This allows organizations to upgrade their Oracle databases without disrupting their existing data replication processes.

It also allows organizations to keep a legacy system running while also running a new version of the database. GoldenGate can also support replication between different editions of Oracle databases, such as replicating data from an Oracle Enterprise Edition database to an Oracle Standard Edition database.